# sysctl -p return net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra = 2

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, kernel

```
/etc/security/limits.conf
* soft nofile 50000
* hard nofile 50000

sudo sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=16777216
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_rmem='4096 87380 16777216'
sudo sysctl -w net.core.wmem_max=16777216
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_wmem='4096 16384 16777216'
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 20
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
sudo sysctl -w net.core.netdev_max_backlog=10000
sudo sysctl -w net.core.somaxconn=2048
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 2048
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range='15000 65000'
```

I made the following changes.
When i run

```
sysctl -p
```

I get the following output

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra = 2
```

Why? Is that normal?

Comment: have a look at `less /etc/sysctl.conf`. Inside that file you will find the line somewhere, i guess. All lines / commands, that are not comment out will be shown when you pass them with `sysctl -p`.

Comment: net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra = 2 - I see only this line why?

Answer (score 2):

You see only that because it is the only line not commented in /etc/sysctl.conf

net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra = 2 is used when you what to use ipv6 forwarding and also use ipv6 SLAAC. If you dont know what this means you should change the line to: net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra = 1

Changing it to 1 will allow you to automatically get a ipv6 Global or ULA address, only if ipv6 forwarding is set to 0.